# GCM support for ios application when application in background or killed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-cloud-messaging

Hello all i am integrating GCM in iOS application using following link

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start.

I have also uploaded the certificates when configuring the file on defined steps.

I have also succeeded for getting notification,but the problem is that i am not getting the notification when the application is killed or in background.Is there any implementation for getting notification in background or killed ios application as i have searched a lot for that and nothing found fruitful.

So any help will be appreciated Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem and  I posted detailed question later. Luckily, I figured out the problem and it is working for me now. I was not sending data in proper format that got working after I sent data in proper format. My JSON format looks like this.

```
{
"notification":{
"badge":"12",
"alert":"default",
"sound":"default",
"title":"default"
},
"content_available":true,
"to":"YOUR_KEY_HERE"
}
```

Since there isn't details available on your sever implementation. you can refer my question for more information.

[GCM push notification to iOS with content_available (not working to invoke from inactive state)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893152/gcm-push-notification-to-ios-with-content-available-not-working-to-invoke-from)

Comment: i have already implemented it before your answer they put it in note, which i have not seen but after getting this problem i show their detail document.

Comment: I found that to get the alert to actually appear on iOS (instead of a silent alert), you need to add "body":"hello world" to the "notification" dictionary.

Comment: That would be so  useful. Thank you Jeremy.